# how to split data from text file and create separate columns at a specific position by giving title for each column

Tags: python, file, split, txt, file-read

Each line is formatted in the following way: `MM-DD-YYYY:Price`

```
01-03-2000:1.312
01-10-2000:1.304
01-17-2000:1.318
01-24-2000:1.354
01-31-2000:1.355
02-07-2000:1.364
02-14-2000:1.394
02-21-2000:1.443
02-28-2000:1.458
03-06-2000:1.539
```

I want this type of output but no idea how to do it.

```
Date Price  (cents/kwh) 
01-03-2000  1.312 
01-10-2000  1.304 
01-17-2000  1.318 
01-24-2000  1.354 
01-31-2000  1.355
```

Comment: You should, write some codes  even if they are incomplete. We will help you from where you are stuck. You can at least write a code to open file and ask for rest of the things.

Comment: I tried it but no good, didn't get any idea. okay I'll do that way next time. it was my first time using it so I just asked the question.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure but your input and output looks very much the same. You want it as a table form if my understanding is right.

```py
import pandas as pd

raw_data = ""
with open("text_file.txt", "r") as file:
    raw_data = file.read()

cols = ["Date", "Price (cents/kwh)"]

vals = [dat.split(":") for dat in raw_data.split(" ")]
dct = {cols[i]: [x[i] for x in vals] for i in range(len(cols))}
df = pd.DataFrame(dct)
print(df)
```

Output

```
         Date    Amt
0  01-03-2000  1.312
1  01-10-2000  1.304
2  01-17-2000  1.318
3  01-24-2000  1.354
4  01-31-2000  1.355
5  02-07-2000  1.364
6  02-14-2000  1.394
7  02-21-2000  1.443
8  02-28-2000  1.458
9  03-06-2000  1.539
```

Comment: yess man this is what I wanted to do but this code is too advanced, I have no idea aout the "PANDA" . Anyway thank you for solving this one, I'll figure it out. thank you